# Possible causes of duplicate requests to Signal-R hub (different ConnnectionIDs)

Tags: iframe, websocket, web-crawler, signalr, http-proxy

Our web-application is exhibiting an issue whereby we're seeing duplicate requests from a single user action (all details *except* ConnectionId are the same) in our Signal-R hub.

Assuming the first request was received at T0 then we saw duplicate requests at (approximately)

- T0 + 2:00
- T0 + 2:30
- T0 + 3:30
- T0 + 8:00

Effectively, the client-side JavaScript code sets up a connection to a Signal-R hub, when the user clicks the submit button it invokes a method on the hub (kicks off procesing in the back-end).

The problem has only started recently in production - we haven't changed any relevant code (client-side nor SignalR hub). The web-app is deployed in a corporate environment (users use IE11 via Citrix). I note that (presumably due to firewalls) SignalR is using forever-frames (rather than web-sockets etc).

In our logs (from the Signnal-R hub) the user-agent appears as `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3)`

The client code looks along the lines of

```
// Setup
self.myHub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.debug("SignalR Hub Connected");
});
...
// When handling user action
self.myHub.server.someHubMethod(param1, param2);
```

Basically, I'm stumped as to what is going on / where I should be looking. My thoughts are that there is some **caching proxy/web accelerator/spider or similar** which is somehow replaying the requests.

Comment: When using Forever-frame, client requests to server are traditional AJAX, according to https://kevgriffin.com/signalr-transports-explained/